# Generated URL in SugarCRM to Show Up in List View - Add Records to Database

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I'm trying to figure out how to modify a module in SugarPro, version 6.0.4.  The  module contains a "key" that is basically a string of characters and this key I would like to append to a base URL and have it be a new field (`keys_c`) in the module.  There are thousands of these keys so it would be nice if this could be generated automatically.

I got it to work as expected with an exception (and misunderstanding).  The `base_url{key}` in the Generate URL option for the module field works but it only displays in the module Detail View.  In the module List View it does not show up.  I looked through all the `listviewdefs.php` files I could find and they all seemed to be OK, but perhaps I don't know what to look for.

The result should look like this:

`example.com?page=key&key=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g`

To recap:  this `base_url{key}` works but only shows up the module's Detail View.  In the Edit View the field is missing (eg, not editable) and the list view, also missing.  The goal here is to get it to show up in the List View.

Then I looked in the database and the new field shows up as `keys_c`, for custom.  In fact, the database shows a new table called `keys_cstm`, adjacent to the keys table.  The new `keys_cstm` table has an `id_c` and `keys_c` rows.  So now I have `keys` and `keys_cstm` tables.  The default value for the `keys_c` is:

`example.com?page=key&key={key}`

But then in Sugar when I go to the Detail View for one of these keys (this works), I see the new field (good) and then in the database a new record is created.

It looks like the value doesn't end up in the database, and is generated on the fly.  I guess this is what is meant by "Generate URL".  So my question becomes:  how to generate all these URLs and store them in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of this option in Sugar is to create a link on the fly.  I've used this function correctly and it works as expected.  However, the problem is, I want something else from the system that is not available.